# Split long column into several columns and print them side by side

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-columns

Using this code:

```
import string


for i, j in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1):
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, j))
```

I get the following output:

```
1: A
2: B
3: C
4: D
5: E
6: F
7: G
8: H
9: I
10: J
11: K
12: L
13: M
14: N
15: O
...
```

What I am looking for is this:

```
0: A              5: F             ....
1: B              6: G
2: C              7: H
3: D              8: I
4: E              9: J
5: F              10: K
```

Is there a way to split a long column into smaller ones and print them side by side?

(Note: the example above is simply for illustrating the output. The actual contents printed can be very different)

Comment: it will be easier to print `0,1,2 \n 3,4, 5` is that ok ?

Comment: would it be ok to print row wise, like `0:A      1:B` on first line , `2:C      3:D` on second line and so on?

Comment: @AnandSKumar It has to be column-wise.

Comment: @user5061 AnandSKumar solution's is column wise

Comment: What defines the number of rows?

Comment: Have a look about DataFrames, I think that might be usefull here.

Comment: There is not definite value for max rows. I am mostly interested in displaying the values within less than 1/2 of a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python3 , You can try this function if you need column wise printing -

```
def listPrinter(lst, cols):
    l = len(lst)
    rs = int(l/cols)
    for i in range(rs):
        for j in range(cols):
            print(lst[i + rs*j] , end='\t')
        print('')
```

Please note, the argument `lst` to the above function is the list of what is to be printed.

Then call this function using -

```
lst = []        
for i, j in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1):
    lst.append('{}: {}'.format(i, j))

listPrinter(lst,2)
```

This would output -

```
1: A    14: N
2: B    15: O
3: C    16: P
4: D    17: Q
5: E    18: R
6: F    19: S
7: G    20: T
8: H    21: U
9: I    22: V
10: J   23: W
11: K   24: X
12: L   25: Y
13: M   26: Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way to do it without changing up your script:

```
import string

for i, j in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1):
    if(i%2==0):
        print('{}: {}'.format(i, j))
    else:
        print('{}: {}\t'.format(i, j)),
```